# save springboot output to elasticsearch engine

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have rest API through which I am sending and getting massages to the Kafka server using spring-boot. Now I want to save those messages to elasticsearch. How to do it can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a systematic job in which case, is somehow like setting up a database storage architecture.
TO BE SIMPLE AND SHORT: 
First you need to decide which ES version you want to use, because there are some breaking changes between ES 2.x to 7.x. And those differences may affect the way you design the schema of your storage.
Assume you use latest 7.x ES, you will need to create index(es) where you want the data fetched from kafka to be stored into. Checkout https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html 
Later you have indexes created, you need to apply and learn some basic knowledge about ES high level rest client and low level rest client. The low level rest client enables you the basic connection to ES cluster via HTTP. And high level rest client apis give you sufficient ways to do ops like documents CRUD, search, aggregations for your data. You can easily find dependencies via maven and use them in your Spring Boot Application. Checkout https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html